# Close window with JavaScript background script? (Firefox Extension)

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am currently writing a Firefox extension that opens a new window in my background script. When a user clicks a button on a page the background script executes and opens the window.

So far I have:

```
// content script
downloadMod(linkToOpen); //button clicked
function downloadMod(url) {
    // var test = window.open(url, '_blank');
    var myPort = browser.runtime.connect({ name: "cac410c4672fff93bf0d3186636d8876de3dfeb6@temporary-addon"});
    myPort.postMessage({ greeting: url });
}
```

In my background script (the script the above code connects too) I have:

```
//background script
portFromCS.onMessage.addListener(function (m) {
        var test = browser.windows.create({
            url: m.greeting,
            allowScriptsToClose: true,
        });
```

**NOTE:** all the code works as expected. However, the trouble comes when closing the window.

I have tried variations of *self.close()*, *window.close()*. I even created a function to wait 5 seconds to load the newly created window and then close the page to no avail. All of my attempts come back with the error:

**Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script.**

I thought this error was supposed to be removed with the *allowScriptsToClose* flag?

Comment: You can only close a window via JS if it was opened with window.open().

Comment: @marekful This is weird. So I just tried the window.open(url) way, unfortunately no window opens in my browser.

Comment: Popup windows are generally blocked by default in modern browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close a window you created with browser.windows.create, you need to use browser.windows.remove.

So:

```
let windowId;

browser.windows.create({url: "http://google.be"}).then((data) => {
    windowId = data.id;
});

// Sometime later, use windowId to close the window
setTimeout(function(){
    browser.windows.remove(windowId);
}, 5000);
```

Comment: I see now, is there a way to find the tabId for the newly opened window?

Comment: I think you mean windowId. I added an example. If you want tab id, I suggest you look at browser.tabs.query which takes a windowId and converts it into a list of tab objects, including their ids.